# Reaction norms model in R

Tags: r, modeling

Anyone knows any R package/function to run a reaction norms model for the analysis of genotype × environment interactions? I don't know if shuch models could be performed using the lme4 or the MCMCglmm packages.

Answer (score 2):

I answered myself. I found the following paper where the lme4 package is used to perform a reaction norm analysis: [Methods in Ecology and Evolution 2011(2), 362–374](http://wildevolution.biology.ed.ac.uk/publications/Martin11%20MEE.pdf).
However, if someone can provide more information about this kinds of models, I would appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to analyse GxE using any mixed effects model package in R, but selecting one really depends upon your data: [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html), [ASreml-R](http://www.vsni.co.uk/software/asreml), [MCMCglmm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MCMCglmm/index.html) are some of your options.

Here are some papers that might help:

- [Bolker et al (2009) TREE](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0169534709000196) is great, and be sure to look at the supplementary materials.
- [Wilson et al (2009) JAE](http://www.wildanimalmodels.org/tiki-download_wiki_attachment.php?attId=22) is generally useful, but especially so if you are using a pedigree.